MD5 output of function throws InvalidDigest Message: The Content-MD5 specified is invalid for s3
Problem: I take a user string and want to set it as the MD5 checksum header using the S3 C++ SDK
I have this code to convert a string to an MD5 checksum string which I got from the openssl website:


std::string md5(const std::string &str){
  unsigned char hash[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

  MD5_CTX md5;
  MD5_Init(&md5);
  MD5_Update(&md5, str.c_str(), str.size());
  MD5_Final(hash, &md5);

  std::stringstream ss;

  for(int i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
    ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>( hash[i] );
  }
  return ss.str();
}



And I simply take the string and request.SetContentMD5(checksum); the output of the function.
However, I keep getting the following error:
[InvalidDigest - Unable to parse ExceptionName: InvalidDigest Message: The Content-MD5 specified is invalid.]

And I have no idea why that is the case. It seems like I am doing the try thing in terms of the conversion, but maybe the output is correct for S3 API?
An example of the output is dd129879d51e72af42ad4f21f47f87c5

The AWS SDK expects the hash to be base64 encoded, your example hash should be 3RKYedUecq9CrU8h9H+HxQ==
